# Django queryset foreign key conversion

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 3 models:

```
class User:
   ...

Class Item:
   ...

Class Storage:
    user = foreignkey(user)
    item = foreignkey(item)
```

Now I have user_id, I want to use the user_id to see all the item this user have:

```
storage_list = Storage.objects.filter(user__id = user_id)
```

After that I get confused. I tried the following, none of them work.

```
storage_list.item.all()
storage_list.item_set.all()
```

Comment: Please don't paraphrase your models, include the actual relevant parts of the model. Either of those options are possibly valid for an *instance*, not a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `storage_list` translates into a list. The `.item_set.all()` methods are only valid on the actual objects in the list.

Basic rule that I try to use: ask for what you want. In your case, you really want to have the items, not the storage objects. So something like this:

```
Item.objects.filter(storage__user__id=user_id)
```

So: items which are connected with a user through a storage object. Django will translate that into the proper SQL joins for you.

Note that you don't need to do the `__id` for user. You can omit that part as django by default will look at the primary key. So:

```
Item.objects.filter(storage__user=user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  sry i have to ask another question here, if in class storage, I have a field 'date_added'. I want to list the them with the items, how do I do that ?   Thx again

Comment: Something like this: `Item.objects.filter(storage__user=user_id).values('id', 'somefield', 'storage__date_added')` . For even more fancy functionality, look at annotate/aggregate: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/ .